# Help in interpreting AUC values from ordinal variables

Tags: machine-learning, classification, biostatistics, diagnostic

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me the benefit of using area under ROC for evaluating agreements between two raters.

Here is an example from two raters on, let's say, clinical time series visualizing the rhythmicity of heart beats. The raters rated the rhythmicity using a scale from 0 (normal) to extremely severe (4).

Is the AUC a good measure for ordinal variables? How can we interpret AUC values? How can we calculate specificity and sensitivity values for each class?

Please note that the AUC values in the table are tentative.

[image]